# Round up currency returned from geoplugin currency converter - PHP

Tags: php

I am using a popular geoplugin to send a amount to and then currency convert it based on the user IP. What comes back in this case is £7.62. I want to round it up and drop the decimals. So in this case £8.

I have tried a few things but all i get is a long number output, like: 165439.

```
<?php
require_once('/resources/geoplugin/geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();

$minDeposit = $output[$fname]['mindeposit'];
$convertMinDeposit = $geoplugin->convert($minDeposit);
echo $convertMinDeposit;
?>
```

Comment: Try `$geoplugin->convert($minDeposit, 0)`, second argument seems like wanted accuracy

Comment: Boom!

You the man. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition of `convert` is

```
function convert($amount, $float=2, $symbol=true) { ... }
```

so second argument can be used to define wanted accuracy, i.e. use

```
$convertMinDeposit = $geoplugin->convert($minDeposit, 0);
```